# What if you want to separate the available data in BigQuery for each agency?

Tags: google-bigquery

I work at an advertising agency.

We have been asked to implement GCP (BigQuery) for an advertiser in our commercial distribution.
I've been told that each agency should have different access rights to BigQuery.

I think it is possible to divide the permissions by project.
Can we have the following configuration?

■Project 1
・BigQuery is used.
・The data is stored in the advertising area.
・Browse and edit permissions are given only to agency A

■Project 2
・Use BigQuery
・Store data in the CRM domain
・Only agency B is authorized to view and edit the data.

Comment: If you have different projects, you can configure completely different permissions. In any case, if you want to give different `read` permissions (but not edit permissions on the data) what usually BigQuery recommends is to have all your data in tables and to create different views for different permissions. You could create different views that filter the data of the agencies and give each agency permissions to their own view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I see that I have to create a view, and I understand that it is the same mechanism as Google Analytics.